# Define default role

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, roles

I am using spring MVC, spring security and hibernate in my application.

When clicking submit on the registration form, I want that the registered user get a default role, which is USER.

This is the class securityConfiguration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;


@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login", "/registration").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/home/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
    //.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
    .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
 }

}
```

And this is the customUserDetailsService :

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.findBySso(ssoId);
    System.out.println("User : "+user);
    if(user==null){
        System.out.println("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
        return new     org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getSsoId(),   user.getPassword(), 
             user.getState().equals("Active"), true, true, true,   getGrantedAuthorities(user));
 }


private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user){
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for(UserProfile userProfile : user.getUserProfiles()){
        System.out.println("UserProfile : "+userProfile);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+userProfile.getType()));
    }
    System.out.print("authorities :"+authorities);
    return authorities;
 }

 }
```

Any idea please, how can I add a default role ?

Comment: You should write a controller for `/registration` and save the user in the database with the default role you have defined.

Comment: this is the part of my controller that contains registration 

 //new user
 @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
  User user = new User();
  model.addAttribute("user", user);
  return "registration";
 }
 
 //save user
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/registration" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String saveUser(User user, ModelMap model) {
  service.saveUser(user);
  model.addAttribute("user ", user);
  //return "registration";
  return "redirect:/login";
 }
I don't know HOW and WHERE to create a default user ?

Comment: There is no such default role/user. These requirements goes to your business logic. inside your `/registration` handler you should create and save the user in a database for example. Layering/decoupling concerns is up to you. Spring recommends @Controller to handles requests, @Service to handle business logic (build a user object/entity) and @Repository to handle data layer (save user entity via hibernate in your case). I think first you should write some console apps and understand how the flow works without spring.

Comment: I think, my question wasn't clear enough. By default I don't mean a role proposed by spring.
I mean, a role, that should be automatically attribute each new registred user